# popupMessage.showAsDropDown() generating null pointer exception

Tags: android, popup, navigation-drawer

I am receiving a null pointer exception that I would like some assistance in understanding why. I am creating a custom pull-down drawer. I have a view, that appears over my Activity on button press (for now, until I implement the fling). This is how I am setting up my PopupWindow

```
popupMessage = new PopupWindow(view, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        popupMessage.setContentView(view);
        // Clear the default translucent background
        popupMessage.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        if(userType != null){
            if (userType.contentEquals("kid")) {
                popupMessage.setFocusable(false);
            } else {
                popupMessage.setFocusable(true);
            }
        }
        popupMessage.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupMessage.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        popupMessage.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);
        popupMessage.update();

        // Icon is an imageVIew ** This is where the null pointer occurs **
        popupMessage.showAsDropDown(icon, 0, -(35+8));
```

Why would this cause a null pointer exception? I have also tried

```
popupMessage.showAtLocation(icon, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

Here are my logs

[image]

Comment: You the man Mike, you the man! This is clear to me. Thank you! If you put in an answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: It's cool. Give it to Rawa. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

popupMessage is obviously not null since you are able to do methods on the instance before the null pointer. Thus my guess is that icon is null, please confirm if this is the case.

```
popupMessage.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupMessage.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
popupMessage.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);
popupMessage.update();

// Icon is an imageVIew ** This is where the null pointer occurs **
popupMessage.showAsDropDown(icon, 0, -(35+8));
```

Comment: This is correct. Thank you Rawa and Mike. My popup is working well now. Cheers!